# Confusion regarding how exactly file operations get set up for a Linux Character Device Driver

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, device-driver

I am currently reading Linux Device Drivers Volume 3 by Oreilly, and I had a question regarding file operations are setup for a specific device driver.

My current understanding is that in a character device driver in Linux, the cdev structs need to be allocated initialized in the device driver initialization function and passed to `int cdev_add(struct cdev *dev, dev_t num, unsigned int count);`.

Once this is all done, the kernel now associates the file operations specified in the `struct file_operations` with the `struct cdev` added.

My confusion comes when I try to understand what is happening in the device drivers `open(struct inode *, struct file *)` function. We are given both a file pointer as well as a inode pointer. Both of these structures contain `struct file_operations *` field, one in `inode -> i_cdev -> ops` and `file -> f_op`.

Are these fields referencing the same `file_operations` structure per device?

I also realize that I might be able to change the value of the `file_operations` structure. If I decide to edit a field within the structure, will the change be reflected once I exit the `open()` function? If so, what is the point of this functionality?

Sorry if I am asking too much within this post. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: By the time it gets to the `open()` function, `file->f_op` and `inode->i_cdev->ops` should be pointing to the same `struct file_operations` from your driver. It's not a good idea to modify the contents of the `struct file_operations` within the `open()`, but it is possible to switch `file->f_op` to point to a different `struct file_operations` using a combination of `fops_get()` and `replace_fops()`. See `misc_open()` in "drivers/char/misc.c" for an example.

Comment: Also, the LDDv3 book is very old, so the `fops_get()` and `replace_fops()` functions probably didn't exist when the book was written.

Answer (score 0):

The comment by Ian Abbott above basically answers my question.

> By the time it gets to the `open()` function, `file->f_op` and `inode->i_cdev->ops` should be pointing to the same `struct file_operations` from your driver. It's not a good idea to modify the contents of the struct file_operations within the `open()`, but it is possible to switch `file->f_op` to point to a different `struct file_operations` using a combination of `fops_get()` and `replace_fops()`. See `misc_open()` in "drivers/char/misc.c" for an example. – Ian Abbott 10 hours

Thankyou!!